# std::basic_string template specialization

Tags: c++, string, templates, specialization

I'm trying to create my own string class using std::basic_string<> with a custom allocator.  It's seems to be mostly working thanks in large part to other related topics on stackoverflow.  But I really want this to be a drop in replacement of std::string. To that end, it needs to assignable to/from std:string.  I tried overloading assignment operators and such but I can't seem to get that working.

The end goal here is to be able to log/track memory allocations for strings in existing code by replacing std::string.  If there's a better way of doing that, I'd like to hear it as well.

This is an embedded application so my options with 3rd party tools is limited.

Here's a sample app with the code I have already.

dave

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace mw_allocator_namespace
{
    int mw_allocator_space =0;

        template <typename T>
        class mw_allocator: public std::allocator<T>
        {
public:
                typedef size_t size_type;
                typedef T* pointer;
                typedef const T* const_pointer;

                template<typename _Tp1>
                struct rebind
                {
                        typedef mw_allocator<_Tp1> other;
                };

                pointer allocate(size_type n, const void *hint=0)
                {
                        pointer p = std::allocator<T>::allocate(n, hint);
                        mw_allocator_space += n*sizeof(T);
                        cout << hex << " Alloc: " << n << " : " << n*sizeof(T) << " (" << reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(p) << ")" << endl;
                        return p;
                }

                void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n)
                {
                        cout << hex << " Dealloc: " << n << " : " << n*sizeof(T) << " (" << reinterpret_cast<unsigned long long>(p) << ")" << endl;
                        mw_allocator_space -= n*sizeof(T);
                        std::allocator<T>::deallocate(p, n);
                }

                mw_allocator() throw(): std::allocator<T>() { cout << " Hello allocator!" << endl; }
                mw_allocator(const mw_allocator &a) throw(): std::allocator<T>(a) { }
                template <class U>
                mw_allocator(const mw_allocator<U> &a) throw(): std::allocator<T>(a) { }
                ~mw_allocator() throw() { }

        };
}

typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, mw_allocator_namespace::mw_allocator<char> > my_string;


int main() {

    string s1("Hello World1");
    my_string ms1;

#if 0
    // This doesn't work
    ms1 = s1;
#else
    // This does...
    ms1 = s1.c_str();
#endif

    cout << "ms1: " << ms1 << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can derive a class from `my_string` and provide conversion to/from `std::string`.

Comment: For other operators you can write your own overload in the allocator's namespace and rely on ADL to find them, but the assignment operator has to be a class member function, so you'll have to write a derived class.